# How to get changes to files in a git repo while omitting new files

Tags: git, diff

I have a git repo with a folder that contains files that are auto-generated source code. Overtime, there were some slight manual modifications made to that code. I am now in a position where I need to regenerate the files but I don't want to miss any of the changes that were made.

What I'd like to do is get a diff of all changes made to that folder over time, but to exclude the original 'add' of each file. That way I could just apply the diff to the new set of files.

There is one more important detail: not all files were added at the same time. The adds are mixed in with the edits. So it's not as simple as generating a diff starting from a specific commit.

Any ideas?

MORE CONTEXT:

- The auto generated files are SOAP proxy classes that are generated from WSDL files
- We are dealing with more than one service and so the classes were added as they were needed.
- We received an updated server VM with WSDLs that contain minor fixes
- The tool used to generate the proxy classes has some incomplete implementations and so the changes made to those files were work arounds

SEEDS:

- Is there a way to know the SHA of the first commit of a file? A flavor of `git log` with `grep` or `sed` I guess?
- Perhaps get a count of commits on a specific file where 1 == no changes only an insert and I could grep those out?

Comment: You have become wedged by lack of foresight in the past... Do the job manually (while scripting it). **Then fix the procedures**, prevent it from happening again. I'd do a manual squash/merge bash script _per generated file_ and simply run that multiple times. I hope for your sake that no renames are involved :)

Comment: why can't you just regenerate the files from the current version …?

Comment: A custom script is what I am envisioning for now, I was mostly curious to see if I was overlooking something that git could do for me.

Comment: @knittl, I think the issue is that the generated files will change (perhaps) dramatically and he just wants to re-apply the changes that he made to the previously-generated files, so just re-generating and diff/merging with the current version would show all the auto-generated changes too...

Comment: The changes to the auto generated code will actually be very minor.  They are changes from a maintenance release of web services.  But even if I could get a diff that didn't apply to the new files would be a step forward as I could at least get a better view of what was changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you still have the old copy of the WSDLs, being a good source control user and all.  With that in mind, I would do the following:

- Create and checkout a new branch from way back before any of the
  files in question were added.
- Generate the classes using the old WSDLs and commit.
- Generate the classes using the new WSDLs and commit.
- Checkout master and merge the new branch in.

That will merge the differences of the auto-generated files with your manual tweaks.

Keep that branch around, so that every time the WSDLs change, you can check that branch out and repeat the last two steps.  Basically, that branch should always contain only the auto-generated files.

Comment: This is a good suggestion.  It's a bit simplified since the original files (from the same WSDL) are added incrementally as they are needed.  So the trick would be to always add these auto generated files to the branch and merge it into master?  And then make all changes in master?

Comment: Also, it might be interesting to note that we have 30+ WSDLs which is why we didn't generate and commit everything in one shot.  We were adding only the ones we needed as the features were being implemented.  Though that would have simplified this process.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if they were added incrementally in `master` or not.  You can add them all in one chunk in the `autogen` branch, as long as the branch was created from a point _before_ they were all added to `master`, and isn't merged until a point _after_ they were all added.  You won't be able to build anything useful out of `autogen`, but you don't need to.  It's sole purpose is to help you merge that subset of files.

Answer (score 1):

Revised answer:

You will need some script that will walk through that directory and using each file get the initial commit with 
`git log --format=%H fileName | tail -1`

And than get the diff with:
 `git diff ^output_of_above SHA_last_commit fileName`

Comment: I need a recursive solution.. there are a lot of files.

Comment: Sorry about that, I misread your question. I just updated the answer.

Comment: I still don't think this works.. the two SHAs can be different for each file.  Also wouldn't "SHA_first_commit ^SHA_last_commit" give me every change except for the last one?

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding your question.  This will give you everything that changed in foldername/* between the two commits you specify.  Is that what you want?

Comment: OK. So I'd probably be looking for something like ^first last instead then since I don't want to include the initial addition of the file.  But this still doesn't solve the real problem.  There is no single SHA_first for all files since some were added subsequently.

Comment: Yeah your syntax is correct, I'm dyslexic this morning.  If you only want the manually changes, I think you're going to have to come up with some script to automate the diff for each file, starting after it was added to the repo.

Comment: You can get the initial commit with `git log --diff-filter=A -- <filename>` (looks for "changes" to this file where it was "Added")

Comment: you also don't need to specify the `last_commit` in the second part if you're only interested in HEAD (as it seems in this case) as it will default to that anyways (but its probably better to keep it there in case someone else has a _similar_ issue where they're not interested in HEAD (i.e. for posterity), just sayin')

Comment: @johnny I figured it would be best to explicitly state where you want the last commit.  No reason to assume that HEAD will be at that same point.

Comment: @johnny (and Andy) Thanks!  I think it's getting obvious that a script is required to do this on a file by file basis.  Your suggestions get me closer.  I suppose I can just append each diff output to an all encompassing diff file.